# How to choose the default directory Pantheon-files starts in

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon

Pantheon is playing games with me.

For a while, it has been starting at the Downloads Directory, which is what  I want. I have opened a new directory, and I think closed it while in it. 
So now it keeps opening on that pointless directory.

Is there a way to specify the default initial directory?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pantheon-files saves by default the places that were opened (tabs and directories). You can however change these settings with `dconf-editor` under the schema `org.pantheon.files.preferences`:

- `restore-tabs` if you set this to `false` it does not remember the last places opened
- `tab-info-list` contains the saved list of tabs and directories

So you can either turn off the behaviour with the first setting or change the directory/directories with the second one.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the default directory (the one that is loaded when you restore tabs is off or if you close the last tab) is hard-coded to be the user home directory.  So if you want to return to the Downloads directory on re-opening then you have to make sure that that folder is open when you close Files.

You could try requesting a feature to be able set the default directory to something else at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files.