# How to disable remember last position (directory) in apps?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-terminal, files

I noticed that every time I open a new window of Files and Terminal, it goes directly to the previous working directory. How can I disable this completely for all applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find answers for your question at these questions:

- Files: [How to choose the default directory Pantheon-files starts in](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/how-to-choose-the-default-directory-pantheon-files-starts-in/10558#10558)
- Terminal [How to disable last working directory in pantheon-terminal?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/how-to-disable-last-working-directory-in-pantheon-terminal)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any more apps that does this?